# how can i select two pop up in different layers on map openlayers without have problems?

Tags: popup, openlayers, layer

I want to know how to define two popups on one map Openlayers for features on two different layers.
Without having the following problem: I have two type of layers POI and one other, when I add the pop up to the two I can't select the second because the layer is bellow the first and when I hide the first I can get select the second.

```js
function onFeatureSelect(feature) {
          selectedFeature = feature;
          if(feature.layer.name=='POI')
          {
           var html_div="<div class='pop_up'>"+

                         "<div>Nom de POI :"+feature.data["name"]+" </div>"+
                          "<div>Type de POI :"+feature.data["type"]+" </div>"+
                          "<div>Longitude :"+feature.data["lon"]+" </div>"+
                          "<div>Latitude:"+feature.data["lat"]+"</div>"+
                         "</div>";
          }else
          {
            var html_div="<div class='pop_up'><div class='identity'> <div class='user'><div class='cadre'><img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/"+feature.data["image_perso"]+"' alt='image profil' /> </div></div>"+
          "<div class='info'><div class='sub matricule'><div class='ico'> <img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/matricule.png' alt='matricule' /></div><span>"+feature.data["matricule"]+"</span> </div>"+
          "<div class='sub name'><div class='ico'><img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/profil.png' alt='name' /></div><span>"+feature.data["Nom"]+"</span>"+
          " </div><div class='sub Adresse'><div class='ico'><img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/adress.png' alt='adress' /></div><span>"+feature.data["adresse"]+"</span></div>"+
          "</div></div>"+
          "<div class='controle_info'> <div class='first_controle_info'> <div class='first_info'><div class='coord'> <img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/lat.png' alt='coordonnées' />"+
          "<span class='title'>Lat:</span><span>"+feature.data["lat"]+"</span><br/><span class='title'>Lon:</span><span>"+feature.data["lon"]+"</span></div> <div class='state'>"+"<img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/"+feature.data["state"]+"' alt='state'/></div><div class='vitesse'><img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/vitesse.png' alt='vitesse' /><span>"+feature.data["vitesse"] +" KM/H</span></div> </div>"+
          "<div  class='off' onclick='confirm_off(\""+feature.data["matricule"]+"\");'><img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/power-off.png' title='Arrêt le véhicule à distance' />"+
          "</div></a> </div>"+"<div class='second_controle_info'> <div class='satellite'><img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/sat.png' alt='Satellite'/><span>"+feature.data["sat"]+" Sats</span></div>"+
          "<div class='courant'><img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/energy.png' alt='courant'/> </div><div class='battery'><img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/empty_battery.png' alt='' /></div><div class='angle'>"+
          "<img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/angle.png' alt='angle' /><span>"+feature.data["angle"]+"&deg;</span></div> <div class='precision'><img src='<?php echo URL; ?>public/gfleet/assets/gfleet/images/popup/prcision.png' alt='precision' /><span>"+feature.data["precision"]+" m</span></div>"+

          "</div>"+"</div></div>";
          }
```